# Java parse Object

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax

I hava a javascript object that im passing back to java via ajax:

```
var jsonData = {   
        "testJson" : "abc",  
        "userId" : "123" 
};
```

When I println the map it looks like:

```
key: jsondata value:[object Object]
```

How can I properly parse the object?

Comment: Read about parsing json objects

Comment: do not include anything but the object to the string you pass to java. `{ ... }`

Comment: Is this a javascript or java question? In javascript the posted code defines  an object called `jsonData`. This would need to be converted into a string ( using `JSON.stringify` ) before passing back to the server.

Comment: @Traktor53. That was my problem...I didnt turn the object to json before sending it back....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GSON in java:

```
class MyObject() {
  String testJson;
  String userId;

  public void setTestJson(String testJson) {
    this.testJson=testJson;
  }
  public String getTestJson() {
    return testJson;
  }
  ... Same for userId
}

And then create a GSON object:

class SomeClass {
  public void parseMyJson(String json) {
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    MyObject mo=gson.fromJson(json,MyObject.class);
  }
}
```

In which `mo` now contains you json object with just the use of getters and setters

Answer (score 0):

I hope, this can help you:
`int userId = object.getInt("userId");`

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html

Answer (score 0):

As posted the code defines a javascript object called jsonData. This can be converted into a string ( using JSON.stringify ) before passing back to the server:

```
var jsonData = {   
    "testJson" : "abc",  
    "userId" : "123" 
};
var jsonString = JSON.stringify( jasonData);
```

or alternatively in trivial cases by defining the JSON string directly:

```
var jsonString = `{"testJson" : "abc",  "userId" : "123" }';
```